# Creating an Equal Area Spatial Grid Over a Large Area (R or Python)

Tags: python, r, geospatial

I am facing a challenge trying to create a 12km spatial grid covering the African continent with open source tools. The main challenge appears to be that most of these tools are based on projected (metric) coordinate reference systems (CRS), which are inaccurate for very large areas. I need grid creating software based on geographic CRS. To illustrate the problem in R:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(magrittr)

# Bounding box for Africa
africa_bbox <- rbind(c(-26, 55), c(-36, 38))
dimnames(africa_bbox) <- list(c("lon", "lat"), c("min", "max"))
africa_bbox %<>% t()
print(africa_bbox)
#>     lon lat
#> min -26 -36
#> max  55  38

# Creating a geometry
africa_sfc <- africa_bbox %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "EPSG:4326") %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% st_as_sfc() 
print(africa_sfc)
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -26 ymin: -36 xmax: 55 ymax: 38
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POLYGON ((-26 -36, 55 -36, 55 38, -26 38, -26 -...

st_area(africa_sfc)   # Area of grid
#> 7.706798e+13 [m^2]
# Now this unfortunately does not work with Geodetic CRS
st_make_grid(africa_sfc, cellsize = c(12000, 12000)) 
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -26 ymin: -36 xmax: 11974 ymax: 11964
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POLYGON ((-26 -36, 11974 -36, 11974 11964, -26 ...

# To make it work I need to project to metric CRS.
# I use UTM 34, which is in the center of Africa, see: https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm
africa_sfc_metric <- africa_sfc %>% st_transform("EPSG:32634") 
print(africa_sfc_metric)
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -3842510 ymin: -5189967 xmax: 3613422 ymax: 5419593
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N
#> POLYGON ((-3842510 -5189967, 3613422 -4567059, ...

# Now computing the grid.
africa_12km <- st_make_grid(africa_sfc_metric, cellsize = c(12000, 12000)) 
head(africa_12km, 3)
#> Geometry set for 3 features 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -3842510 ymin: -5189967 xmax: -3806510 ymax: -5177967
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N
#> POLYGON ((-3842510 -5189967, -3830510 -5189967,...
#> POLYGON ((-3830510 -5189967, -3818510 -5189967,...
#> POLYGON ((-3818510 -5189967, -3806510 -5189967,...

length(africa_12km) # Number of squares
#> [1] 550470
areas = st_area(africa_12km)
all(unclass(signif(areas, 4)) == 12000^2) # Checking sizes
#> [1] TRUE
sum(areas) / st_area(africa_sfc) # Grid is 2.85% too large
#> 1.028542 [1]

# To put this into perspective, I compute the area of a 12km border around the continent
perimeter_12km_area <- africa_sfc %>% st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% st_length() %>% multiply_by(12000)
# That's 0.5% of the area, so the 2.85% too large is significant
perimeter_12km_area / st_area(africa_sfc)
#> 0.004725914 [1/m]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Now of course I could somehow reverse engineer the Haversine Formula to come up with a program that creates an accurate grid over a large area, but first I would like to ask if there are already software solutions to this (preferably R or Python) that I am not aware of.

Comment: The [dggridR](https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR) package offers a solution based on hexagonal grid at different fixed resolutions, though not exactly 12km but around 95km2 (there are discrete resolution choices): ```library(dggridR);
dgg_10km <- dgconstruct(area = 144, metric = TRUE, resround = "nearest");
africa_10km_hex <- dgrectgrid(dgg_10km, minlon = -26, minlat = -36, maxlon = 55, maxlat = 38, frame = FALSE);
africa_10km_hex_sf <- st_as_sf(africa_10km_hex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do the impossible. You can either have a 12km x 12km grid in a projected CRS that is approximately 12km x 12km and approximately square on the ground, or you have a regular Z by Z degrees grid in a lat-long projection that is approximately square and approximately 12km x 12 km on the ground.

You can't chop a spherical surface into exact 12km x 12km squares where the distance is measured along the surface.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it is not possible to create a perfect 12km grid with an equal amount of squares at every latitude, but it is possible to create an approximation that does a pretty good job e.g. by converting km to degrees at the equator `degrees = km / (40075.017 / 360)` rescaling longitudes to better reflect distance e.g.  `lon_scaled = lon * cos(lat * pi/180)` does a decent job, and creating a `degrees`grid using latitudes and the rescaled longitudes. I'm sure there are more precise and better ways of doing this. The hexagonal grid of `dggridR` is already quite sophisticated...